# Simple C program labelled as virus

Tags: c

I was writing a program to input a string and output alternate characters in the string and I could compile it once, and building it made my antivirus program report that it is a virus (Gen:variant.graftor.74557).

Does any of my code causes something malicious to be called a virus

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void altchar()
{
    char a[50];
    printf("Enter a string");
    gets(a);                    
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i+=2)
        printf("%c",*(a+i));
}
int main()
{
    altchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Other c programs compiles very smoothly with no clashes with my AV.

**Update:**

My AV has no problem with gets() function, and other programs that use gets works smoothly.

**Update 2:**

By the way, I can run the program exactly once, then it is moved to quarantine.

And the output is nothing and the compiler tells me

> Process returned 1971248979 (0x757EDF53) execution time: -0.000 s

For curious minds, I use Bitdefender Antivirus!

Comment: `gets()` is dangerous in that it is possible to overrun the buffer. In this case, more than 49 characters input would result in buffer overflow. Don't know if that is causing the alert though. Try using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets).

Comment: You have a potential buffer overflow in your code. Maybe your antivirus is clever enough to detect that as a threat?

Comment: @SergeyL. If gets was the problem other programs I have written with gets in it would also be a virus, but that is not the case.

Comment: `printf("%c",a+i);` is in-correct. You need to deference each alternate array memory location as `*(a + i)`.

Comment: @SunEric. Sorry that was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: In my experience, anti-virus programs are not particular clever at all.

Comment: Note that **`gets` was removed from the C language in the C2011** Standard. You better start using `fgets` or `gets_s` now.

Comment: Unrelated to the main question, note that you're calling `strlen(a)` on every iteration of the loop.  You'd save a bunch of cycles by saving the result of `strlen(a)` before the loop (e.g., `int len = strlen(a)` and `for( ...; i < len; ... ) { ... }`).

Answer (score 4):

The "virus" detected is actually a placeholder name for the F-Secure [generic trojan detector](http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan_w32_graftor.shtml). It looks into programs for suspect behaviour. Unfortunately that kind of analysis is bound to sometimes producing false positives.

Maybe your harmless code matches some known malware behaviour on a byte code level? Try making a small change to your code and see if the problem goes away. Otherwise you can submit your program (info on the paged linked above) as a false positive to help them improve their database.

Comment: I know from experience that F-Secure is a particularly stupid anti-virus program. It cannot co-exist with Windows programming tools, it will always whine about your program being a potential virus. Telling it to ignore the program won't help either, since you are constantly generating a new executable. The solution: uninstall F-secure.

Comment: @Lundin, or you can just tell it to ignore the directory where you are working.

Comment: @Ben Or, I couldn't care less about why F-Secure whines and keep doing my job, which is to do programming. Uninstalling the damn thing works wonderfully. At home, I have been connected to the internet since 1994, I've never had neither a virus nor an anti-virus. At work, I have had plenty of severe issues caused by anti-viruses though. They are quite efficient at ruining your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The classic methodology of an antivirus software is to take a few bytes (very well chosen bytes) from an infected file and use those as an identifier string ... it searches the executables and if the bytes match with some bytes from an executable (this check is most of the time done when opening (running) an executable, or when performing a full system scan) then it marks it as a virus.

Fix your code (as per comments), and recompile ... see what happens :)